# No sound or no mic imput on Dell Latitude 3410

Tags: sound, dell

Ive bought a new Dell Latitude 3410.
I installed Ubuntu 20.10 but no sound available. The microphone did work after install.
I wrote the command
echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf
on terminal and the sound issue was fixed but the microphone stopped working.

Any ideas how can I make them all work?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you found any solution?